# How to remove and append from loop array Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

i have a form like this.
[image]

when i change from country, how to remove this form and append again from looping array. if data only one, show Add Form Button and if data > 1, first form always show Add Form Button, for 2nd,3th.. show Delete Form Button.

this is my data : [{"gamename":"nama game 1","gamelink":"link game 1","image_link":"link gambar 1","startfrom":"1"},{"gamename":"nama game 2","gamelink":"link game 2","image_link":"link gambar 2","startfrom":"2"}]

This is my script, but not working:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('formadd');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
var json = response.data[0].games;
var array = JSON.parse(json);
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
$('.formadd').append(

'<div id="game-form-'+i+'">'+
            '<hr>'+
                '<div class="form-group">'+
                    '<div class="col-md-3">'+

                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-6">'+
                        '<label for="gamename" class="control-label col-sm-2">Game Name</label>'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-bottom: 5px">'+
                                '<input class="form-control valid" name="gamename[]" type="text" id="gamename" aria-invalid="false" required>'+
                            '</div>'+

                            '<label for="gamelink" class="control-label col-sm-2">Game Link</label>'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-bottom: 5px">'+
                                '<input class="form-control" name="gamelink[]" type="text" id="gamelink" required>'+
                            '</div>'+

                            '<label for="image_link" class="control-label col-sm-2">Image Link</label>'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-bottom: 5px">'+
                                '<input class="form-control" name="image_link[]" type="text" id="image_link" required>'+
                            '</div>'+

                            '<label for="startfrom" class="control-label col-sm-2">Start From</label>'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-bottom: 5px">'+
                                '<input class="form-control" name="startfrom[]" type="text" id="startfrom" required>'+
                            '</div>'+

                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" onclick="deleteForm('+i+')" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-left">Delete Form</a></div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>' 
            );
}
```

i want to like this:
[image]

Comment: Where does "i" come from?

Comment: You don't need JSON.parse there

Answer (score 0):

May be you did not use consistent id and class for `#formadd`

I tried to reproduce use only id it worked

```js
var json = [{"gamename":"nama game 1","gamelink":"link game 1","image_link":"link gambar 1","startfrom":"1"},{"gamename":"nama game 2","gamelink":"link game 2","image_link":"link gambar 2","startfrom":"2"}]


var elem = document.getElementById('formadd');
//elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
var i = 0;
var array = json;
$('#formadd').append(

'<div id="game-form-'+i+'">'+
            '<hr>'+
                '<div class="form-group">'+
                    '<div class="col-md-3">'+

                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-6">'+
                        '<label for="gamename" class="control-label col-sm-2">Game Name</label>'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-bottom: 5px">'+
                                '<input class="form-control valid" name="gamename[]" type="text" id="gamename" aria-invalid="false" required>'+
                            '</div>'+

                            '<label for="gamelink" class="control-label col-sm-2">Game Link</label>'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-bottom: 5px">'+
                                '<input class="form-control" name="gamelink[]" type="text" id="gamelink" required>'+
                            '</div>'+

                            '<label for="image_link" class="control-label col-sm-2">Image Link</label>'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-bottom: 5px">'+
                                '<input class="form-control" name="image_link[]" type="text" id="image_link" required>'+
                            '</div>'+

                            '<label for="startfrom" class="control-label col-sm-2">Start From</label>'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-bottom: 5px">'+
                                '<input class="form-control" name="startfrom[]" type="text" id="startfrom" required>'+
                            '</div>'+

                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" onclick="deleteForm('+i+')" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-left">Delete Form</a></div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>' 
            );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formadd"></form>
```